# Python: &= operator

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, set

When I try to or/and two sets using `&=` and `|=` operator, I got some weird result.

```
s1 = {1,2,3}
s2 = {2,3,4}
tmp = s1
tmp &= s2
```

As expected, tmp will be {2,3}, but I don't know why `s1` also changed it value to {2,3}.

However, if I do:

```
tmp = tmp & s2
```

Then, `s1` will be unchanged! Can anyone explain for me what happens underneath `&=` operator?

Comment: You should copy `s1` by value and not by reference

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`&=` (`set.__iadd__`)](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/5ea093a41198/Objects/setobject.c#l1318) for `set` is implemented differently with [`&` (`set.__add`)](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/5ea093a41198/Objects/setobject.c#l1310).

`set &= ...` is implemented using [`set.intersection_update`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection_update) which update the set in-place.

---

Relevant CPython code (`Object/setobject.c`):

```
set_iand(PySetObject *so, PyObject *other)
{
    PyObject *result;

    if (!PyAnySet_Check(other))
        Py_RETURN_NOTIMPLEMENTED;
    result = set_intersection_update(so, other); // <----
    if (result == NULL)
        return NULL;
    Py_DECREF(result);
    Py_INCREF(so);
    return (PyObject *)so;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It's called `intersection_update`. *return set s keeping only elements also found in t*.  As you see in this picture;

[image]

You are re-building first set with intersection.

Answer (score 3):

Copy the set by value instead of by refrerence

```
tmp = set(s1)
```

(As `s1` is an instance of `set`)

Answer (score 0):

It's not the `&=` operator that's causing the unexpected result, it's how Python works with storing objects in memory, and referincing them with variables (names).

Everything in Python is an object, and it is stored somewhere in memory. Declaring a variable just tells Python that you are referencing a specific object that is stored at a specific location in memory, using the variable name as a reference to that object.

You can get some information about the memory location of the object using the builtin `id()` function, example:

```
s1 = {1,2,3}
s2 = {2,3,4}
tmp = s1
id(tmp)
1763330653544
id(s1)
1763330653544
```

Some information about builtin `id()` function:

> Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer which is
>   guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its
>   lifetime. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same
>   id() value.
>
> CPython implementation detail: This is the address of the object in memory.

[Link to Python docs in id() function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id)

As you can see, by using the `id()` function, the object being referenced by the names `tmp` and `s1` is the same, since the integer value returned is the same.

So, when you alter either one, the other changes as wel. Actually what I am saying in the last sentence isn't technically correct, since there is no 'either', just one set object in memory with two different references (`tmp` and `s1`).

```
s1 = {3, 4, 5}
s2 = s1
s2.add(6)
s1
{3, 4, 5, 6}
id(s1)
1763330653320
id(s2)
1763330653320
```

It's not always this simple though, so if you want to understand this I recommend looking up Python memory management, and variable referencing.

Real Python seems do to a good job explaining object referencing (with names/variables), [link to the page](https://realpython.com/python-variables/).